# 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Entry>' does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable'

Tags: c#

While using `AsQueryable` with type `Collection<Entry>` getting above exception. Please find below code for reference.

```
public override Task<IQueryable<T>> AllAsync(ReadOptions options = null)
{
        var entry = this.Collection.AsQueryable(options);
        dynamic EntryList;
        EntryList = new Collection<Entry>();

        try
        {
            dynamic result = entry.ToList();

            if (result != null && result.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (Entry entry in result)
                {
                    foreach (var item in entry.ModifiedEntries)
                    {
                        Attribute attr;
                        Entry obj = new Entry();
                        obj.Attributes = new Collection<Attribute>();

                        foreach (var attributes in item.Value.Attribute)
                        {
                            attr = new DflAttribute();
                            attr.Name = attributes.Key;
                            attr.Value = attributes.Value.Value;
                            obj.Attributes.Add(attr);
                        }

                        EntryList.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(EntryList.AsQueryable());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw Error.ToRepositoryException(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are your variables defined as `dynamic`? Can't you solve it by either making the method return a `Task<IQueryable<Entry>>` or by restricting `T` to `Entry`, like `where T: Entry` after the method definition? I am only saying because from what I see what you try to do in code, you seem to avoid the `T` completely, so I don't really see the need for the used generics...

Comment: `EntryList` is dynamic... either define it as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` or cast it before calling `AsQueryable` https://dotnetfiddle.net/OqP5Xl . But I'm not really sure why you are using dynamic.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually `T` is referring to Base class of `Entry` which is `BEntry` but I need to return object of `Entry`. That's why I am using `dynamic` keyword here.

Comment: @AniruddhaKumbhar From the code you have shown, there is no way we could know how `T` is defined and how you are using it, any chance you post more code? As said by TheGeneral and FernandoCallejon, the `AsQueryable` requires an `IEnumerable<T>`, but I still think that if you just try to "cheat" with dynamic, then there is something wrong with your design in the first place...

Comment: This code is generic. So I cannot use `List` here. Is there any other way than `Collection` so that i will be able to achieve above requirement?

Comment: `T` is restricted to `base` class only so i cannot directly refer to it.

Comment: No, this code is not generic, the definition of it is, but you are circumventing the problem with a cheat, which leads me still to believe that your design is flawed

Comment: I mean my code is not generic but previous code is generic. I have overriden the function and adding this new code to achieve the result only. The limitation here is that I need the out with `EntryList` object only

Comment: Can you add the class definition to your question?

Comment: Actually I am not able to share the code. But why it is required? Are you not able to understand my question and comments?

Comment: I would like to see if T is restricted to BEntry or not, if it is, then it's quite easy to change your code, if it is not, then your code will always be semi. If you are not allowed to share your code, then you shouldn't have posted this question in the first place

Comment: I have changed the code and posted it here. I can not show you whole definition but I can show some of it. Is this okay?

Comment: `public class EntryMongoRepository<T> : DEntryMongoRepository<T, DateTimeOffset>, IEntryRepository<T, DateTimeOffset> where T : BEntry
    {` I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @AniruddhaKumbhar then it is quite easy, your entrylist should be collection<T> and your addition should be BEntry entry = new Entry() and you can skip the Dynamics in that case

Comment: `EntryList.Add(obj);` here I am getting error as cannot covert `BEntry` to `T`

Comment: Above error is gone when I used `T obj = new Entry() as T;` but I am not able to get one field which is in Entry class only.

Comment: @AniruddhaKumbhar Does [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6SAwHU) help? I'm not entirely happy about the `ChangeType`, but it changes at least not a lot from your basecode (you could however do it differently, like for example by adding a `Func<input, T>` as a parameter

Comment: On the other hand, you could also make it work if you fix `EntryMongoRepository` to the `Entry` or `BEntry` class like [so](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sr2RPf)